# cygwin git thinks that file previously had different mode

Tags: git, cygwin, msysgit

I manually built latest version of git for cygwin. The only problem is that it thinks that file mode changed (from 644 to 755). Git that is installed in windows doesn't see any changes. actual file mode is 755 (both windows Git and cygwin git shows the same).

So, as a result, 
1) on windows git doesn't show any changes whether `core.filemode` is set to true or false
2) on cygwin git shows changes for modes if `core.filemode` is set to true or unset and doesn't show any changes when `core.filemode` is set to false
Actual file mode is 755.

So, my question is, is there a bug(featue) in windows git (msysgit) that emulates `core.filemode = false` disregarding of option set. Or does cygwin git displays wrong previous file mode. I suppose it's the first, as files are of xml type.

Answer (score 7):

mysysgit doesn't support file permissions well.  It assumes all .exe is 755 and all text is 644.  In my experience, I always have `filemode=false` in the global config for mysysgit.

Using a separate global config for cygwin which has `filemode=true` since cygwin supports `chmod` and you can track the executable bit as needed, but you'd have to commit changes to it from cygwin.

I also noticed, when you clone or init a repo in cygwin, it automatically adds `core.filemode=true` to the local config, which has precedence over global, which will break my suggestion above.

I was able to fix this by `git config --local -e` and deleting the `filemode` entry, leaving the global config as the only definition to use.

The downside is every repo you clone will have it set to `true`, so you'll need to delete it out of there per repo.  I haven't found a way to prevent this on cygwin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.   I also found this to work `git config --local --unset core.filemode`.  This removes that filemode setting from your local config as well.  I noticed that when I ran `git init`, the .git/config file was setting this so I had to unset it in order to avoid the problem described in this question.